# How to route to the route's children path in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to route to a different route in vue after clicking the back button in the browser. Below is what I have done:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if (to.path === '/place-ad') {
      console.log("path is /place-ad")
      next('/place-ad?ad_id=' + 12345)
    } else {
      console.log("path is I don't know")
      next()
    }
```

The problem with the above is that I end up with the error:

```
VueJs Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

If I now change the if statement check to `to.path !== '/place-ad'` then there is no error but it doesn't route me to where I want, in this case the `else` clause gets triggered. I've seen many other similar stackoverflow questions but from what I've seen they all want to reroute to a completely different route. Whereas I'm trying to route to the route's children path.

ie: `/place-ad?ad_id=' + 12345` instead of just `/place-ad`. How do I achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add a query param on a specific route, if it is not set?

You can also do it like this in your `place-ad` page component:

```
<script>
export default {
  created () {
    if (!this.$route.query.ad_id) {
      this.$router.push({
        query: {
          ad_id: '12345',
          ...this.$route.query
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or, if you have to stick to the `beforeRouteLeave`, this one should work too:

```
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if (to.path === '/place-ad') {
      if (!to.query.ad_id) {
        return next({
          path: to.path,
          query: {
            ...to.query,
            ad_id: '12345'
          }
        })
      }
    }

    return next()
  }
```